# How to change the thumnail image of associated product on selecting option in configurable ptoduct?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, product-images, associate-products

Hi i want to show all the images of associated product when i click on attribute options in frontend.

Currently it is changing only base image and not showing any other images.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is already built in, with the so-called Configurable Swatches which allow "Product Image Swap".

> You can enable this feature in System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches

One way to configure swap images is to upload images to a configurable product with labels exactly matching the specific option labels (for example, Royal Blue).

Source and full documentation: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html

Comment: its display only one image for associated product. But we need multiple images for associated product also

Comment: yes, i want same, please suggest how can i do that